# Two table view xib file ,call using one table view class methode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In a one view controller xib, I am using three table views.how can I call this table views using one table view class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `UIView` has a `tag` property. You can set different tags (int) to the 2 `UITableViews`

After that:

```
if(tableView.tag == ??) {
    //First Table
} else {
    //Second Table
}
```

However, if there is a lot of different logic for those tables, my advise is to divide the logic into two classes.

Good luck!